Superset plugins yeoman error: Current environment doesn't provides some necessary feature this generator needs
I already have superset up and running on my local machine. I followed the official setup guide and everything has been working perfectly. However, now I am trying to create my own custom charts for my superset dashboards and saw that you can create your own plugins. I started following the setup guide for this on from the apache superset github and everything seemed to be running correctly until I got to running yeomand to setup the plugin.
here is a link to the guide i have been using [https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/howtos/]
I have followed the official setup guide on the superset github. The only thing I did not do was run the yarn commands at the very beginning. I keep running into this issue and I cannot figure out what i need to change.
Is the superset plugin guide out of date?
Is there a better way I can create custom charts in superset?

I went down the path of trying to make plugins work and found that you can use the handlebars chart plugin that is already built into superset to create custom charts using html and css. if you are apart of a software dev team and want to create new charts that will be used multiple times then you can follow the guide on how to incorporate it into a production environment.

I'm not sure I got it right, but try using another version
npm install -g yo@4
